# Video on partial screen

Tags: android, cordova, video, phonegap-plugins

I need to have a video streamed to a tablet using PhoneGap for Android. But here's the thing: I don't want it playing full screen, but only on part of the screen. Is that possible? I tried searching but there seems to be nothing on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the video tag on Android 4.x but not on earlier versions of Android using the video tag. See [my post](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/10/partial-support-for-video-tag-in.html) on it.

If you need to support earlier versions of Android you'll need to setup and activity with [multiple views](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android).